# Find folder by name then copy files

Tags: linux, macos, unix, terminal

I need to find subdirectories called "child" and copy the files in those folders to a new directory. Can't get it to work.

I can get as far as finding the subdirectories but I can't copy the files from them.

```
> find /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO-1/STUDIO-COMPLETE/ISSUETRAK/2016/03_2016 -type d -iname child
```

The above will find all subdirectories in 03_2016 named "child" but how do I now copy the files inside those directories?

I tried this but the problem is that it seems to want to copy the directories themselves and not just the files:

```
> find /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO-1/STUDIO-COMPLETE/ISSUETRAK/2016/03_2016 -type d -iname child | xargs cp '{}' /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO-1/STUDIO-COMPLETE/ISSUETRAK/TEST \;
```

I can't get it to target only the files.

Answer (score 1):

You're close:

```
> find $YOUR_PATH/03_2016/ -type d -iname child | xargs -I {} find -type f {} | xargs -I {} cp {} /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO-1/STUDIO-COMPLETE/ISSUETRAK/TEST
```

Note: You might overwrite files that share the same name at the final destination

Comment: Ah, I see where you're going. I get the error `-bash: /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/STUDIO-COMPLETE/ISSUETRAK/2016/03_2016: is a directory`, which is referring to the target. Not sure why it's complaining, of course it's a directory.

Comment: make sure the second find is `-type f`

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little cleaner than the above answer:

```
find $(find /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO-1/STUDIO-COMPLETE/ISSUETRAK/2016/03_2016 -type d -iname child | xargs) -type f -exec cp {} /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO-1/STUDIO-COMPLETE/ISSUETRAK/TEST \;
```

Two calls to find, one call to xargs. Like the other answer, this also will overwrite duplicate file names.

Comment: It works, thanks! I see what happened, COMMON-LIC-PHOTO should not have had the -1 at the end (sometimes it mounts twice and does this, a separate issue entirely!).